# Changing content dynamically in WPF window from a few UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have two UserControls, such as `LogInControl` and `CheckControl`. Initially, the window contains `LogInControl` and the login window is changed after a successful login: the window contains `CheckControl`.

It's code from `MainWindow`

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LogInControl logInControl = new LogInControl();
            CheckControl checkControl = new CheckControl();
            logInControl.OnSuccessfulLogin += (senser, e) =>
            {
                ChangeContentControl("Check");
            };

            checkInControl.LogOutClick += (senser, e) =>
            {
                ChangeContentControl("LogIn");
            };
            this.contentControl.Content = logInControl;
        }

        public void ChangeContentControl(string kindContentControl)
        {
            switch (kindContentControl)
            {
                case "LogIn":
                    {
                        ...
                        this.contentControl.Content = new LogInControl();
                    }
                    break;
                case "Check":
                    {
                        ...
                        this.contentControl.Content = new CheckControl();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

It's code from `LogInControl`

```
public event EventHandler OnSuccessfulLogin;
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnSuccessfulLogin?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
```

It works correctly. But 'CheckControl' has the "Logout" button when clicked on this button in the window should appear 'LogInControl' content. But it doesn't happend.

It's code from `CheckControl`

```
public event EventHandler LogOutClick;
        private void logOutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LogOutClick?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
```

`LogOutClick` event tracking stops when you transition to a window with `CheckInControl` (LogOutClick becomes null).
I can not understand why this happens. Help me please.

Comment: 1. Move the subscription of `LogOutClick` Event inside `ChangeContentControl` method or
2. Make the windows decleration global and use the same instance everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that, when you are switching controls, you are creating new ones. The new one doesn't have the events registered. So you are overwriting the previous created with the events registered.

```
switch (kindContentControl)
{
    case "LogIn":
    {
        ...                           
        this.contentControl.Content = new LogInControl(); <- here
                                      ^^^------------
    }
    break;

    case "Check":
    {
        ...
        this.contentControl.Content = new CheckControl(); <- here
    }
    break;
}
```

---

**FIX**: You should assign the previous created controls:

These variables should be fields, because you want to access the same instance in different methods:

```
private LogInControl logInControl = new LogInControl();
private CheckControl checkControl = new CheckControl();
```

and the switch should be like this:

```
switch (kindContentControl)
{
    case "LogIn":
    {
        ...
        this.contentControl.Content = this.logInControl;                    
    }
    break;

    case "Check":
    {
        ...
        this.contentControl.Content = this.checkControl;
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you create 2 instances of each control. the first in constructor, and they are subscribed to event. the second in ChangeContentControl method, and they *do not* have event subscription.

so you can reuse controls by storing them in a local variable

```
LogInControl logInControl = new LogInControl();
CheckControl checkControl = new CheckControl();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    logInControl.OnSuccessfulLogin += (senser, e) =>
    {
        ChangeContentControl("Check");
    };

    checkInControl.LogOutClick += (senser, e) =>
    {
        ChangeContentControl("LogIn");
    };
    this.contentControl.Content = logInControl;
}

public void ChangeContentControl(string kindContentControl)
{
    switch (kindContentControl)
    {
        case "LogIn":
            {
                ...
                this.contentControl.Content = logInControl ;
            }
            break;
        case "Check":
            {
                ...
                this.contentControl.Content = checkControl;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

or subscribe new instances to event as well. Control with subscription is created in a separate method to avoid code duplication

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.contentControl.Content = getLogInControl();
}

private LogInControl getLogInControl()
{
    LogInControl logInControl = new LogInControl();
    logInControl.OnSuccessfulLogin += (senser, e) =>
    {
        ChangeContentControl("Check");
    };
    return logInControl;
}

private CheckControl getCheckControl()
{
    CheckControl checkControl = new CheckControl();
    checkControl.LogOutClick += (senser, e) =>
    {
        ChangeContentControl("LogIn");
    };
    return checkControl;
}

public void ChangeContentControl(string kindContentControl)
{
    switch (kindContentControl)
    {
        case "LogIn":
            {
                ...
                this.contentControl.Content = getLogInControl();
            }
            break;
        case "Check":
            {
                ...
                this.contentControl.Content = getCheckControl();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```